# Combining Multiple Models Into 1 View Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, templates

I am a beginner working on a RoR app that allows users to update their resume with experiences and education. I have two models for these different items and would like to display them together in chronological order. I want to know how to set this up in my profile controller and view.

I'd like to adopt this same practice to a separate part of the app that will combine post and discussion items from users in the same way. However, currently, my focus is on the experience and education portion.

profiles/show.html.erb:

```
    <% if @experiences.any? or @educations.any? %>
<div class="postExpOuter">
    <% @experiences.each do |experience| %>
            <div class="postExp">
                <div>
                    <h2><%= experience.position %></h2>
                    <h3><%= experience.company %> | <%= experience.location %></h3>
                    <h4>
                        <%= experience.start_month %> <%= experience.start_year %>
                        <% if experience.end_year %>
                            <%= " - " + experience.end_month %> <%= experience.end_year %>
                        <% else %>
                            <span> - Present</span>
                        <% end %>
                    </h4>
                </div>
            </div>
    <% end %>
    <% @educations.each do |education| %>
            <div class="postExp">
                <div>
                    <h2><%= education.degree %></h2>
                    <h3><%= education.school %></h3>
                    <h4>
                        <% if education.end_year %>
                            <span>Class of </span><%= education.end_year %>
                        <% else %>
                            <%= education.start_year %><span> - Present</span>
                        <% end %>
                    </h4>
                </div>
            </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

profiles_controller.rb:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find_by_profile_name(params[:id])
    if @user
        @posts = @user.posts.all(:order => "created_at DESC", :limit => 3)
        @experiences = @user.experiences.all(:order => "start_year DESC")
        @educations = @user.educations.all(:order => "start_year DESC")

      @items = (@experiences.to_a + @educations.to_a).sort_by(&:start_year).reverse[0,3]

        render action: :show
    else
        render file: 'public/404', status: 404, formats: [:html] 
    end
  end
end
```

profiles/show.html.erb:

```
<% if @items.any? %>
<div class="postExpOuter">
    <% @items.each do |item| %>
      <% if item.is_a? Experience %>
       <div class="postExp">
            <div>
                <h2><%= item.position %></h2>
                <h3><%= item.company %> | <%= item.location %></h3>
                <h4>
                    <%= item.start_month %> <%= item.start_year %>
                    <% if item.end_year %>
                        <%= " - " + item.end_month %> <%= item.end_year %>
                    <% else %>
                        <span> - Present</span>
                    <% end %>
                </h4>
            </div>
        </div>
      <%- else -%>
        <div class="postExp">
            <div>
                <h2><%= item.degree %></h2>
                <h3><%= item.school %></h3>
                <h4>
                    <% if item.end_year %>
                        <span>Class of </span><%= item.end_year %>
                    <% else %>
                        <%= item.start_year %><span> - Present</span>
                    <% end %>
                </h4>
            </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

just hacked in my browser, don't know if it works directly:

```
<%- (@experiences.to_a + @educations.to_a).sort_by(&:end_year).each do |item| -%>
  <%- if item.is_a? Experience -%>

    your markup here...

  <%- else -%>

   your other markup here...

  <%- end -%>
<%- end -%>
```

haven't written ERB since... uhh, long. basically it's just the following: merge the 2 ActiveRecord-Relations as Arrays into one big Array, sort them by the timestamp you want (you may add `.reverse` at the end if you want). While iterating through the list, check the type of object you have.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked really well, but how would I move it to the profile controller properly?

Comment: I figured it out so far. I'm posting the answer. Thank you again for the help!